# Firebase: Delete data after 60 seconds

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When my users use my application, data is sent to Firebase but I only want the data to be stored for 60 seconds before being deleted.

How to I automatically delete data stored on Firebase after 60 seconds on the server-side and automatically update my RecyclerView client-side?

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing? Please provide your source code.

Comment: I Have Not Any Problem . Main Question Is : How Deleted Data After 60 seconds From FireBase Databae ? No User Side Request delete . I need Send Request delete to firebase from My server Side . thx

Comment: Do you want to know how to delete data in Firebase after 60 seconds?

Comment: Exactly . After 60 seconds need Delete Data From FireBase RealTime DataBase .first option : User Side Send Delete request to fire Base ? two option : Server send request delete to fireBase ? which is better ? thx . caution : 60 seconds from timestamp request is submit .

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm sending in an edit to prevent it from being deleted due to unsalvageability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the handler in your onCompleteListener. Then use the code to delete the specific node after 60 Seconds.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("node_name").child(keyval).removeValue()
  }
}, 60000);
```

Comment: in your opinion For My Project FireBase cloud Messaging Or FireBase RealDataBase which one better ?

Comment: @zobydehkarimi i think your asking firestore or Realtimedatabase.